# WPF - Using CollectionViewSource with ALREADY grouped data

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, collectionviewsource

I have a ViewModel that is used in Windows 8, Android and iOS as part of a Xamarin Project. I now need to display that VM in a ListView in WPF.

That VM exposes some **already** grouped data as `ObservableCollection<GroupedResult<string, SearchResult>>`. GroupResult has a `Key` (String) property and an IEnumerable `Source` property

With a Windows 8 ListView I can assign that data to a CollectionViewSource (CVS), tell the CVS the path to the Items property `PropertyPath("Source")` and it works fine.

However WPF seems to want an ungrouped List fed to its CVS so it can Group it all itself. How do I tell the WPF CVS that the VM contains already Grouped data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that the System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource class in WPF has no IsSourceGrouped or equivalent property so you cannot really tell it that the data is already grouped.

You basically have two options.

1. Ungroup the source collection and set the Source property of the CollectionViewSource to the ungrouped collection and add a PropertyGroupDescription to its GroupDescriptions collection as usual: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742542(v=vs.110).aspx
2. Set the Source to the grouped collection and define an ItemTemplate for the Grouping objects:

   ```
   public MainWindow()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       List<User> items = new List<User>();
       items.Add(new User() { Name = "John Doe", Age = 42, Sex = SexType.Male });
       items.Add(new User() { Name = "Jane Doe", Age = 39, Sex = SexType.Female });
       items.Add(new User() { Name = "Sammy Doe", Age = 13, Sex = SexType.Male });

       var result =
           from x in items
           group x by x.Sex into g
           orderby g.Key
           select g;

       listBox.ItemsSource = result;
   }
   ```

---

```
   <ListBox x:Name="listBox">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Expander Header="{Binding Key}">
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </Expander>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: I am happy to assume the Source is Grouped and set the Templates to fit it. I will be displaying in a ListView rather than ListBox, if i wanted the Sections to be always expanded, if not empty, can you suggest a container other than Expander?

Comment: What's wrong with the Expander? You can set its IsExpanded to true to have it expanded by default. And if you don't want to be able to expand/collapse the groups you could just remove the expander and use the ListBox or ItemsControl as the root panel of the DataTemplate.

Comment: I am trying to mimic the GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="True" I have used so successfuly in Win8. As you suggested I will replace expander with somehting else. Thanks

Comment: I have it all working via option 2 but it is very slow with large datasets. I am wondering if doing it this way has caused me to lose Virtualization. I am guessing but it looks like the "Name" property of every single row in the Grouped set is being Read rather than just those needed to paint current View

Comment: After reading this Question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569506/listbox-not-virtualizing I can see that the inner ListBox\ListView needs a MaxHeight set so that you still get Virtualisation. You should note that in your answer

Comment: Virtualization will be applied unless the outer ListBox is a child of a StackPanel or some other kind of panel that measures its children with an infinite height. If you put the ListBox that I posted in a window with a Grid as its root panel you should see that the virtualization works as expected.

Comment: I have the ListView in a Popup, Apparently there are issues with virtualization in Popups. I will see if that can be fixed. I have tried this with Option 1 (Flattened data) and its the same problem

Comment: I don't really see how this is related to your original question of how to display already grouped data but since Popup is a "window" of its own you should either set the Height of the Popup itself or the ListBox in it to enable virtualization. Virtualization is not supported when the top-most panel doesn't have any height constraint.